# In array it is storing NULL instead of PDF file name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

```
public class cp extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView ListPdf;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    List<upload> uploadPdf;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cp);

        ListPdf = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
        uploadPdf = new ArrayList<>();
        ViewAllPdf();
    }

    private void ViewAllPdf() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("year_1");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot PostSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    upload Pdf = PostSnapShot.getValue(upload.class);
                    uploadPdf.add(Pdf);

                }

                String[] uploads = new String[uploadPdf.size()];
                for(int i=0;i<uploads.length;i++){
                    uploads[i] = uploadPdf.get(i).getName();
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,uploads);
                ListPdf.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

upload class

```
public class upload {

    public String name;

    public upload() {

        this.name = name;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**In uploads[ ] it is storing null instead of file name,i cannot figure out what's the problem. I tried logcat for debuging but it shows Pdf object has three files but in uploads[ ] it stores NULL. Please look into it**

Firebase database screenshot

[image]

Comment: Log `uploadPdf.size()` underneath this for loop `for(DataSnapshot PostSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()`

Comment: Try adding ```public upload() {}``` in your ```Upload``` class.

Comment: @MalikBilal It is already added

Comment: @HB. please explain what you want to say

Comment: I can't see it in your posted code.

Comment: @MalikBilal it is in upload class

Comment: @MalikBilal `upload()` is public.

Comment: Remove this line ```this.name = name;``` from it.

Comment: @Amritesh Add `Log.e("Size ", "Size = "+uploadPdf.size());` underneath your first for loop  - `for(DataSnapshot PostSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())` and run the application, see the log in Logcat.

Comment: @MalikBilal its not working

Comment: @HB. it shows Size = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is your POJO class `Upload`. See an example from Firebase Documentation

```
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Also the fields name in your Realtime Database doesn't match with your POJO class.

Comment: I added 2nd constructor also just like in example but it doesn't work and what were the fields names then please suggest me.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I am new to android and java please help me i am unable to understand from that.